# laravel и public

Tags: php, laravel

Необходимо чтобы в ссылке на главную страницу не было /public (версия laravel последняя). Использую данный код в .htaccess (виртуальный хост на apache и перенос index для решения задачи не подойдет).
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
Выдает ошибку на главной странице:
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: можно же конечно создать в корне index.php c кодом require_once 'public/index.php', но мне кажется, что это костыль

Comment: Обычно в Laravel используется нечто вроде `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Что за хостинг? На обычном хостинге публичную директорию не изменишь, но на большинстве хостингов структура каталогов такова, что в папке сайта есть вложенная публичная категория (обычно `www` или `public_html`), ставишь лару в корень сайта, и при необходимости переименовываешь публичную директорию, потом добавляешь привязку в `/bootstrap/app.php`

Comment: разворачиваю на своей машине, сервер xampp

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, что Вам нужно убрать из url `/public/...`, то можно сделать так:

В корне сайта добавить файл `.htaccess` с таким содержимым:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L] # Перенаправляем весь запрос в папку public
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку как и раньше ("Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."). Использую xampp (последней версии)

Comment: Опишите детально что и за чем Вы делаете, что пишете в адресной строке и что ожидаете в результате.

Comment: Пишу http://localhost/laravel-test.by/ хочу чтобы отображалась index страница http://localhost/laravel-test.by/public/

Comment: А какие настройки апача? В какой директории лежит проект..? И соответственно настройки хоста для него

Comment: Стандартные настройки xampp